# UITableView cuts my table view, cannot view the entire TableView[Xamarin, iOS]

Tags: uitableview, scroll, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to make a custom TableView that has big heights, but when i run it i can only access 2 of my 5 rows in the table(in the example i provided)
Here is a screen shot of how i am viewing my table : https://i.stack.imgur.com/07EnJ.png
Here is the link to my Table Source : http://pastebin.com/B7U2BEd8

Here is my view controller :

```
    unclass[] lol= new unclass[amount];
    for (nint i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        lol [i] = new unclass ();
        Console.WriteLine ("item created");
    }

    UITableView _table;
    _table  = new UITableView{ Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (0, 30, View.Bounds.Width, 3000),Source= new TableSource(lol) };
    _table.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;

    for (nint i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        lol [i].imager =  await this.LoadImage (links[i]); //loads image from the net to table
    }
    View.AddSubview (_table);
}
```

I really don't understand why this is happening

Comment: Please do not post links to offsite code listings.  Take the time to include the relevant pieces of code directly in your post.

Comment: The problem is that i don't understand why i am getting the result i am getting that is why i included my whole Table Source.

Comment: You should still post the code inline, not link to an external site.  And you are setting your Table's height to 3000 - try setting it to the screen bounds instead.

Comment: Sorry for that, i will post my code in line next time.
I changed 3000 to "View.Bounds.Height" , instead of showing only 2 it shows 2 and 1/3 now but it still isn't showing 5.

Comment: So your question is essentially "why doesn't my TableView scroll?"  There are hundreds of hits on "tableview doesn't scroll" on SO and other sites.  Have you read any of them?

Comment: Yes i did, but none of them are in my situation. i have everything set up correctly according to me, it just does not work

Answer (score 2):

Your TableSource is not the problem, I tested it with a blank table.

Also as Jason said you will need to change the table's frame height to "View.Bounds.Height - 30" -30 to compensate for your Y position. I created a simple example below that show all 5 cells. So it might be the way that you are adding the table or if there is anything else in the viewController. Are you able to post more of your view controller's code?

```
using UIKit;
using CoreGraphics;
using System;
using Foundation;

namespace SO_Xam_actvity
{
    public class bigTableViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            UITableView _table;
            _table  = new UITableView{ Frame = new CGRect (0, 30, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height-30),Source= new TableSource(new [] {1,1,1,1,1}) };
            _table.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
            View.AddSubview (_table);
        }
    }

    public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        int[] tableItems;
        string cellIdentifier = bigTableViewCell.Key;

        public TableSource (int[] items)
        {
            tableItems = items;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return tableItems.Length;
        }

        public override nfloat GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return 200;
        }
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier) as bigTableViewCell;
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = new bigTableViewCell();
            }
            cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = $"{indexPath.Row}";
            return cell;

        }
    }


    public class bigTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("bigTableViewCell");

        public bigTableViewCell () : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, Key)
        {
            TextLabel.Text = "TextLabel";
        }
    }
}
```